# Switch template routing to Express from Angular app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have an app where the entire routing is handled by the angular app. For instance I have many angular routes such as the following:

```
$routeProvider
        .when("/users",{ controller: "userController", templateUrl: "partials/users.html" })
```

and on the back end app I have

```
router.get('/partials/:name', function(req, res, next) {    
   var name = req.params.name;
  res.render('admin/partials/' + name);
});
```

This set-up also uses the ugly localhost/#/ hack. I want to switch all routing to Express and get rid of this hack in the process. What options do I have, in terms of least amount of files that will need to be modified.

Basically I want to return full rendered HTML with dynamic data generated from API routes for that particular endpoint integrated with it (possibly with the use of an HTML preprocessor such as Jade), and stop using Angular's to render templates and then embed API data to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What options do I have, in terms of least amount of files that will need to be modified.

is hard to decide without knowing your code and it's dependencies.

But I would suggest to have a closer look at [jade conditionals](http://jade-lang.com/reference/conditionals/), [jade includes](http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/) and  [jade extends](http://jade-lang.com/reference/extends/). I use the jade preprocessor from within express apps to prepare jade templates and are very satisfied with that solution.

If you generate HTML-pages without any further dynamic content consider to use express' static feature.

If you have to do some very special processing of jades output you can do it within the callback before storing/delivering the file.

A snipped:

```
jade.compile('./templates/jade/remotecontrol.jade',
  {title:'Remotecontrol',
   copt:customoptions,
   key:project.key,
   objects:JSON.stringify(project.objects),
   buttons:{login:true},
   controls:{joystick:true},
   forms:{login:true}},
   {callback:storeTo,
     storeTo:__dirname+'/projects/'+project.key+'/stk/index.html',
     pretty:true})
```

For a template like (please recognize the "include ../../../" as the path has to be relative from the template, not the node app)

```
doctype html
html(lang="de")
  head
    title #{title}
    meta(charset="UTF-8")    
    include ../../../templates/jade/favicon.jade
    meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no")
    link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/client.css")

    script.
      var objectsToInject=!{objects};
      var key='#{key}';

    ...

  body
    include ../../../templates/jade/loading.jade
    div.bodycontainer()
      button.beforebgr(name="fullscreen" id="fullscreen" class="fullscreen") Fullscreen
      if controls.joystick
        div.draggable(id="divjoystick" class="draggable ui-widget-content")
          include ../../../templates/jade/joystickbase-svg.jade
          include ../../../templates/jade/joystick-svg.jade

      ...

      - var scriptname="'libs/js/remotecontrol.js'"
      include ../../../templates/jade/loadscript.jade
```